# Xcode 9 not finding assets after using xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I downloaded Xcode 10 to test some new features on a project, Now when I reopen the same project on Xcode 9. It seems that Xcode can't find any assets ( images)

This would work fine on Xcode 10 :

```
let image = UIImage(named: "AsunnyDay")
// this would find the correct image
```

However, on Xcode 9

```
let image = UIImage(named: "AsunnyDay")
//image would be nil
```

I guess it's something related to XCode 10 categorizing the assets as either for dark appearance or light. but I don't understand why would Xcode 9 not find them.

Comment: I would not expect a project created in Xcode 10 to be at all backward compatible to Xcode 9. The release notes say something about that IIRC.

Comment: It's actually created in Xcode 9. I just ran it on xcode 10 then reran it on Xcode 9

Comment: Ok but when you used the asset catalog it presumably updated its format... Check those release notes

Comment: Yes most probably that's the issue. Just like when xcode 9 updated the storyboard format.

Comment: There is nothing in the release notes to suggest this is a known or expected issue so it may be a bug. Can you identify what has changed in the asset catalog?

Comment: I just opened and built a project in Xcode 10 and I could not see any changes in the version numbers in the asset catalog. In fact, the only change in the files on disk was the creation of .DS_Store

Answer (score 6):

Guys this is how I fixed it.

1. Open project in Xcode 10 beta
2. Go to the assets
3. Select all the images you have
4. In the inspector, you will have an option to choose the appearance type. Choose `Any, Light,Dark`
   [image: Xcode 10]
   [image: Appearance]
5. This will create extra placeholders for other images:
   [image: Extra Assets]
6. Open Project in Xcode 9. the assets will look something like this 
   [image: Extra Assets]
7. Reorder the 1x , 2x , 3x into place.
   [image: Reorder]
8. Delete the extra unassigned placeholders
   [image: Final]
9. Done

Answer (score 0):

For me i just reran the project using Xcode 10 and then reverted back to Xcode 9 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command line tool and clear your derived data first.
Clear your project.

After that force quit Xcode and reopen it.
It solved my assets warning problem.

[image]

Hope it will help you.